# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'NewEmpClass' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: asp.net-core

added model class and created dbcontext followed by controllers and view but getting following error:

[image]

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'NewEmpClass' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.'

Answer (score 0):

Yes the error is mentioned in error message as well.
have markered primary key value in database table but not defined in code leve.
Mention your model class row column is a primary key column like this= **[key]**.

```
public class NewEmpClass
{
    [Key]
    public int Empid { get; set; }
    public string Empname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Salary { get; set; }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KKAl.png)